# Possible to redirect elsewhere after saving an entry?

Tags: control-panel, entry, redirect, saving

I'm editing an entry in the CP...

```
mysite.com/admin/entries/mySection/33-my-awesome-entry
```

Now when I **save** this entry, it will redirect me back to the entry index page. However, I'd like to override this behavior, and get redirected to a *different* page upon saving.

**Is it possible to override the redirect target when saving an entry?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!**

Assuming you're using some sort of business logic plugin (if you don't have one, [get one](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic)), then simply put this code in your main `*Plugin.php` file...

```php
public function init()
{

    // Trigger template hook
    craft()->templates->hook('cp.entries.edit', function(&$context)
    {

        // Check to ensure that you're in the right section
        if ('mySection' == $context['sectionHandle'])
        {

            // Specify the preferred URI
            $uri = 'special-page/'.$context['entry']->uri;

            // Set the "Save" button redirect
            craft()->templates->includeJs("
                $(function () {
                    $('input[name=\"redirect\"]').val('{$uri}');
                });
            ");

            // Set the `cmd + s` shortcut redirect
            $context['saveShortcutRedirect'] = $uri;

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: This *almost* works in Craft 3, changing to `Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.entries.edit', function(array &$context) {}` and `Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs()`. The `saveShortcutRedirect` part works fine for cmd+s saves, but even if you use the hashed version of the $uri (via `Craft::$app->getSecurity()->hashData($uri)`) it 1) triggers the "something has changed" behavior so even if you don't actually edit anything in the form, it warns you before leaving the page and 2) redirects to `/admin{$uri}`. Anybody have hints on how to implement a redirect-after-save in Craft 3?

Comment: @natebeaty I'd recommend posting a [new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to link back to this thread for reference!