# Redirect after saving an entry

Tags: control-panel, redirect, saveentry

The question was already asked ([Possible to redirect elsewhere after saving an entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/possible-to-redirect-elsewhere-after-saving-an-entry)) but this was about Craft `2.x`.

Up until now I used the following code in my plugin (I took it from one of the comments from the same question):

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.entries.edit', function (array &$context) {
    if (isset ($context['section']['type']) && $context['section']['type'] === 'single')
    {
        Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs("
            $(function () {
                $('input[name=\"redirect\"]').val('/');
            });
        ");
    }
});
```

The code did the job, but after I updated to `3.1.32.1`, it stopped working, every time after entry was saved the following exception was thrown:

> HTTP 400 – Bad Request – yii\web\BadRequestHttpException
>   Request contained an invalid body param

Stacktrace:

```
yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Request contained an invalid body param in .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php:651
Stack trace:
#0 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(314): craft\web\Request->getValidatedBodyParam('redirect')
#1 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/EntriesController.php(595): craft\web\Controller->redirectToPostedUrl(Object(craft\elements\Entry))
#2 [internal function]: craft\controllers\EntriesController->actionSaveEntry()
#3 .../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 .../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#5 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(109): yii\base\Controller->runAction('save-entry', Array)
#6 .../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('save-entry', Array)
#7 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(297): yii\base\Module->runAction('entries/save-en...', Array)
#8 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(565): craft\web\Application->runAction('entries/save-en...', Array)
#9 .../vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(281): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#10 .../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#11 .../web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Is there any chance to make it work again on `3.1.32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect url always needs to be hashed:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#redirectinput

In Twig you can use `{{ redirectInput(url) }}` which is a shortcut of

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ url|hash }}">
```

But if you need the same in a PHP code you can use

```
Craft::$app->getSecurity()->hashData($url)
```

based on the code how the Twig filter defined in *craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Extension.php*.

Comment: One problem, though. Now after the value of the `<input name='redirect'>` is changed, every time I leave the page, I receive `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.`. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: this behavior is observable only for certain entries, but I could not find any system. Two entries have got exactly the same set of fields, but content is different. One is triggering the alert, another don't.

Comment: The redirect should be a hidden input and the value is always the given url prefixed with a hash when you check the source in a browser. The other half sounds unrelated to your original question, but this is definitely not how the redirection works. I would look for a script or anything else which changes your form data. Check your headers sent to the action.